# No es posible mostrar documento pdf desde el codebehind en un IFrame (Utilizando ASPX y VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

un cordial saludo

estoy intentando abrir un documento pdf en un IFrame, desde el CodeBehind; sin embargo.  no muestra el documento pdf.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">        
function verpdf() {              
                $("#ifrmVisualizadorPDF").css('display','block');
            }
  </script>
```

**ASPX**

```
        <iframe id="ifrmVisualizadorPDF" runat="server" >

        </iframe>
```

**VB.NET (CodeBehind)**

```
Protected Sub gridView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gridView.RowCommand


Try
        Dim index As Integer = 0 : index = CInt(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim visualizarPDF As New HtmlGenericControl("ifrmVisualizadorPDF")
      
    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "VerInforme"
   
            visualizarPDF.Attributes("src") = "documento.pdf"
            Me.udpScripts.Update()
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.Page.GetType, "verpdf", "verpdf();", True)


    End Select
Catch ex As Exception
    Call mt_ShowMessage(ex.Message.Replace("'", " "), MessageType.error)
End Try
  End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias, por sus comentarios

Comment: y que error te sale???

Comment: Estimado Francisco, al agregar la ruta en el src desde el codebehind no se muestra ningún mostrar. Sin embargo, he intentado asignar la ruta del archivo pdf desde jquery, pasándole como parámetro y me muestra el error: <!-- <--no enabled plugin supports this MIME type -->

Answer (score 0):

encontré una solución; sin embargo, no termina de convencerme del todo, pues **es necesario tener instalado el plugin de Adobe Acrobat Reader en el navegador**. A nivel de código la solución es la siguiente:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function verpdf(ruta) {            
            $("#ifrmVisualizadorPDF").attr("src",ruta) 
            $("#ifrmVisualizadorPDF").css('display', 'block');
        
        }
</script>
```

**ASPX**

```
 <!--IFRAME (Visualizar Archivos PDF)-->
                    <iframe id="ifrmVisualizadorPDF" runat="server" scrolling="true">
                      
                    </iframe>
                    <!--/IFRAME (Visualizar Archivos PDF)-->
```

**VB.NET (CodeBehind)**

```
Protected Sub grwSinResp_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grwSinResp.RowCommand
        Try

            Dim index As Integer = 0 : index = CInt(e.CommandArgument)
            Dim ruta As String

            Select Case e.CommandName
                Case "VerInforme"


                    ruta = "carpeta/documento.pdf"
                    Me.udpScripts.Update()

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.Page.GetType, "verpdf", "verpdf('" + ruta + "');", True)

            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            Call mt_ShowMessage(ex.Message.Replace("'", " "), MessageType.error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**Nota:** Mi duda es, ¿por qué cuando asigno directamente la ruta en el atributo "src" del iframe, no es necesario instalar el plugin de acrobat (se visualiza correctamente el documento pdf); pero, cuando quiero asignar la ruta en forma dinámica por jquery, sí es necesario instalar el plugin del acrobat, pues me muestra el error: *no enabled plugin supports this MIME type*?